# How to winterize window AC unit from inside?

Tags: heating, windows, air-conditioning

I have a bunch of AC units in my house that I can't remove during the summer. The windows are too high up for me to access from outside the house. What can I use to seal the window unit - including the "accordion" side pieces, to minimize how much cold air will get in?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to remove them from the outside; these things are generally designed to be installed and removed from inside the house (perhaps with enough strong people helping).

Comment: Yes, I don't want to remove them for other reasons.

Comment: Removing them for the winter is going to be more effective, cheaper (free), and easier than trying to winterize the whole area, but it's your choice.

Comment: Perhaps you can best winterize an AC by pulling it inside, wrapping it with a tarp or heavy trash bag, and storing it back in the window.